# How do I add a description to an app?

Tags: office-365, app

I created an app for Sharepoint and deployed it to app catalog on our intranet. App is created with Visual Studio. I can't find where I can add description for app so that it's packaged with the app. I looked into AppManifest.xml but can't find anything there. This is probably a really easy question to answer if you know where to look.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you upload the app to app catalog site, there you get the option to provide description. `Short Description` and `Description`.

[image]

Comment: So there's no option to package the description with the app in Visual Studio?

Comment: No I don't think so.

Comment: @Garima Not even in Appmanifest.xml Or Elements.xml ?

Comment: Why should end user will update these fields? This should be under the control of developer. Right.?

Comment: True but app is uploaded in app catalog by tenant admin not end user. As far as I know, this is the only place to update description :)